# I'm trying to figure out how to reverse a triangle I created using a given number

Tags: c++

The program should ask a user to enter a number and it forms a triangle using the numbers between 1 and the given number. I came up with a code:

```
cout << "Enter a number: ";
cin >> rows;
for (int y = rows; y > 0; --y)
    {
       for (int x = 1; x <= y; x++)
        {
            cout << x << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

And I would get:

Enter a number: (user inputs number, lets say 7)

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2 
1
```

but I can't seem to get it to:

```
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
* 6 5 4 3 2 1
* * 5 4 3 2 1
* * * 4 3 2 1
* * * * 3 2 1
* * * * * 2 1
* * * * * * 1
```

without it going completely wrong. Any possible tips?

Comment: Which of the 2 outputs is the desired one?

Comment: The second one. Starting with 7 and going to 1 then doing the same thing on the following line but start with 6 and leaving the space as if 7 was still there. @JohnnyMopp

Answer (score 0):

```
    int rows;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> rows;
    for (int y = rows; y > 0; --y)
    {
        for (int x = rows; x > 0; x--)
        {
            if (x <= y) cout << x << " ";
            else cout << "* ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh the if-else statement. I really didn't even' think about that one. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it:

```
cout << "Enter a number: ";
cin >> rows;
for (int y = rows; y > 0; --y)
{
    for(int h = rows-y; h>0; --h){
        cout<<"*";

    }
    for (int x = y; x >= 1; --x)
    {

        cout << x << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```